# Blog for learning Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Are there any blogs dedicated to Objective-C and iPhone development?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](http://www.google.com/reader/bundle/user%2F12133417121205215078%2Fbundle%2Fiphone) is the google reader bundle for the blogs i subscribe to

here is opml file from my reader for iphone category

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<opml version="1.0">
    <head>
        <title>surya subscriptions in Google Reader</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<outline title="iphone" text="iphone">
            <outline text="71²" title="71²" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds2.feedburner.com/71squared" htmlUrl="http://www.71squared.com"/>
            <outline text="Call Me Fishmeal." title="Call Me Fishmeal."
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://wilshipley.com/blog/feed.xml" htmlUrl="http://wilshipley.com/blog/"/>
            <outline text="Cocoa Blogs - Articles"
                title="Cocoa Blogs - Articles" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.cocoablogs.com/feeds/articles-newest.xml" htmlUrl="http://cocoablogs.com/"/>
            <outline text="Cocoa Convert" title="Cocoa Convert"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://cocoaconvert.net/feed/" htmlUrl="http://cocoaconvert.net"/>
            <outline text="Cocoa Is My Girlfriend"
                title="Cocoa Is My Girlfriend" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/CocoaIsMyGirlfriend" htmlUrl="http://www.cimgf.com"/>
            <outline text="Cocoa with Love" title="Cocoa with Love"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/CocoaWithLove" htmlUrl="http://cocoawithlove.com/"/>
            <outline text="Eschatology" title="Eschatology" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://eschatologist.net/blog/?feed=rss2" htmlUrl="http://eschatologist.net/blog"/>
            <outline text="furbo.org" title="furbo.org" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://furbo.org/feed/" htmlUrl="http://furbo.org"/>
            <outline text="Games from Within" title="Games from Within"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds2.feedburner.com/gamesfromwithin/full" htmlUrl="http://gamesfromwithin.com"/>
            <outline text="iBetaTest.com :: All Betas RSS2.0 Feed"
                title="iBetaTest.com :: All Betas RSS2.0 Feed"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds2.feedburner.com/iBetaTestRSS2" htmlUrl="http://ibetatest.com/iphone/controllers/betas"/>
            <outline text="iCodeBlog" title="iCodeBlog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/icodeblog" htmlUrl="http://icodeblog.com"/>
            <outline text="[iOS developer:tips];"
                title="[iOS developer:tips];" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://iosdevelopertips.com/feed" htmlUrl="http://iosDeveloperTips.com"/>
            <outline text="iPhone Development"
                title="iPhone Development" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss" htmlUrl="http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="iPhone Development Blog"
                title="iPhone Development Blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/iPhoneDevelopment" htmlUrl="http://iPhoneIncubator.com/blog"/>
            <outline text="iPhone Programming Blog"
                title="iPhone Programming Blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://adeem.me/blog/feed/" htmlUrl="http://adeem.me/blog"/>
            <outline text="iPhone Software from Satosoft"
                title="iPhone Software from Satosoft" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.satosoft.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php" htmlUrl="http://www.satosoft.com"/>
            <outline text="iPhoneKicks.com" title="iPhoneKicks.com"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/iphonekicks" htmlUrl="http://www.iphonekicks.com/"/>
            <outline text="JohnnyWorks" title="JohnnyWorks" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds2.feedburner.com/Johnnyworks" htmlUrl="http://johnehartzog.com"/>
            <outline text="João Prado Maia's Weblog"
                title="João Prado Maia's Weblog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://pessoal.org/blog/feed/atom/" htmlUrl="http://pessoal.org/blog"/>
            <outline text="Landon Fuller" title="Landon Fuller"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/index.rss" htmlUrl="http://landonf.bikemonkey.org"/>
            <outline text="Luke Hatcher" title="Luke Hatcher" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds2.feedburner.com/lukehatcher" htmlUrl="http://www.lukehatcher.com"/>
            <outline text="Mac Dev" title="Mac Dev" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://morethanmachine.com/macdev/?feed=rss2" htmlUrl="http://morethanmachine.com/macdev"/>
            <outline text="Mobile Orchard" title="Mobile Orchard"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/MobileOrchard" htmlUrl="http://www.mobileorchard.com"/>
            <outline text="Notlost" title="Notlost" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://notlost.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://notlost.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="NotTooBad Blogging"
                title="NotTooBad Blogging" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com"/>
            <outline text="NSBlog" title="NSBlog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/rss.py" htmlUrl="http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/"/>
            <outline text="Planet Cocoa Blog" title="Planet Cocoa Blog"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://planetcocoa.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://planetcocoa.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="shanecrawford.org" title="shanecrawford.org"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/shanecrawfordorg" htmlUrl="http://shanecrawford.org"/>
            <outline text="Streaming Colour Studios"
                title="Streaming Colour Studios" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds2.feedburner.com/StreamingColour" htmlUrl="http://www.streamingcolour.com/blog"/>
            <outline text="tap tap tap" title="tap tap tap" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.taptaptap.com/blog/feed/" htmlUrl="http://www.taptaptap.com/blog"/>
            <outline text="Theobroma Cacao" title="Theobroma Cacao"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://theocacao.com/index.rss" htmlUrl="http://theocacao.com/"/>
            <outline
                text="Things that were not immediately obvious to me"
                title="Things that were not immediately obvious to me"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/ThingsThatWereNotImmediatelyObviousToMe" htmlUrl="http://www.mlsite.net/blog"/>
        </outline>
</body>
</opml>
```

Answer (score 3):

The ones I read regularly:

- http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog
- http://cocoawithlove.com
- http://sigpipe.macromates.com
- http://landonf.bikemonkey.org
- http://mattgemmell.com
- [http://kickingbear.com/blog](http://kickingbear.com/blog/)
- http://wilshipley.com/blog
- http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog

Answer (score 2):

Oleg Begemann at http://oleb.net/blog/ is superb. He also does regular digests of a "best of" roundup of great iOS developer tutorials and links. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

http://icodeblog.com/ is one that I subscribe to

Answer (score 1):

http://idevkit.com/iphonedev/   turned the forum into a blog, covers xcode/apple dev along with toolchain/mobilesubstrate, its a little newer tho