# iPhone (ObjC,CocoaTouch) -> Informations, Tutorials, Blogs, Twitter names, Feeds, Podcasts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

im new to iPhone Dev and searching the web for resources about iPhone Development.

Currently i'm using this resources:

- Apple iPhone Beta Forum
- stackoverflow -> iphone Tags
- iphonedevelopmentbits.com
- icodeblog.com

thanks for every tip :)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546238/blog-for-learning-objective-c/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546238/blog-for-learning-objective-c/) Similar question

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405568/are-you-doing-iphone-development-how-do-you-learn , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232570/what-are-the-best-cocoa-touch-iphone-programming-blogs , among many other questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Jeff Lamarche's Blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/) – Also author of Beginning iPhone Development. Blog has a good intro to OpenGL ES on the iPhone.
- [CocoaDev.com](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease) – Deliberately linked into the Debugging Autorelease articles.
- [Three20](http://groups.google.com/group/three20) – Not a generic iPhone resource but as an open sourced library there is a wealth of information surrounding it and how it does it.
- [Enormego Developers Blog](http://developers.enormego.com/) – Informative Blog with some open sourced libraries of notable interest.

Answer (score 0):

Those are all good resource, I really like this forum as well: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/

Answer (score 0):

If you are after podcasts, iTunesU has some good stuff for beginners. Stanford University have a series of videos for iPhone development.

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225